# Local Logstash SNS Output to goaws SNS topic in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, local, amazon-sns

First of all, if I left anything out please forgive me as this is my first post.

I have docker running goaws and i added a separate container running a python daemon that i wrote. The python daemon reads from the SQS endpoint i have subscribed to my SNS topic and does a POST to a webapp in another docker container running tomcat. All of this works perfectly in one docker-compose.yml. I can publish a message directly to my goaws SNS topic using the python publish API and i recieve the output in elasticsearch which is after my webapp. I view the elasticsearch cluster in Kibana (yet another container I have running).

I wanted to take things a step further and add Logstash to the stack in docker. I cant get logstash SNS output plugin to send a messsage to the goaws SNS topic. It wants to send it to sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com which I dont have credentials for. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: `sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is the [API endpoint hostname](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sns_region) for the SNS service in us-east-1... so, unless your topic isn't in the us-east-1 region, what you are saying "it wants" to do isn't wrong, and it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry it’s not clear. GoAws is a local aws sns sqs service. So it’s running on my machine in Docker. I want my logstash to send messages to my goaws container but I don’t know if a way to tell it to look at http://goaws:4100 as an endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That is much more informative.  I mistakenly assumed you had named an SNS topic (in actual SNS) "goaws" because you were running something also called "goaws" (and I didn't know what that was).